# Riemann-integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let  $f:[0,\infty )\rightarrow R$ a real valued  continous function  such that: $f(x)\neq 0 \quad \forall x>0 \quad$ and

${ (f(x)) }^{ 2 }=2\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ f(t)dt } \quad \forall x\ge 0$.

Prove that $f(x)=x\quad \forall x\ge 0$.

Comment: I tried to try deriving on both sides and reaching the conclusion that f '(x) =1
but I think it is wrong

Comment: No you are right. Now integrate both sides.

Comment: But as we know that f is indeed differentiable in the domain?

Comment: Can you show that if $f$ has one sign and $f^2$ is differentiable then $f$ is also differentiable? (The bad thing that can happen if all you know is that $f^2$ is differentiable is very rapid switching of signs, for example $f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ -1 & x \not \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)f'(x) = f(x) ~\forall x \ge 0.$$

If $x > 0$ then $f'(x) = 1.$ So, $f(x) = x + c$, where $c$ is a constant.

If $x = 0$ then $f(0) = 0.$

So, $c = 0.$ And then, $f(x) = x.$

Comment: once it is continuous its integral is derivable. Once $f(x)^2$ is equal to one derivable function the claim follows.

Comment: it's true, thanks

Comment: @frusciante14 It's slightly more complicated than that, because $(f^2)'$ can exist even when $f'$ does not exist, such as in the example I gave in the comments. But this requires sign changes in $f$ which are prohibited by the continuity assumption.

Comment: @Ian, the function you stated is not even integrable

Comment: @frusciante14 I know. But my point is that "if $f^2$ is differentiable then $f$ is differentiable" is not at all true. However, if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, $f(x_0) \neq 0$ and $g(x)=(f(x))^2$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, with $f'(x_0)=\frac{g'(x_0)}{2f(x_0)}$. Things break if you drop any of these hypotheses, which is why I was saying it is a bit more complicated than you made it sound.

Comment: oki! I got it now. Thank you.